# TailwindCSS TextField, Radiobuttons and Checkboxes looks different

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, tailwind-css

The problem is that the textfields looks so different when I am copying the component code from tailwindcss website and trying to run on my google chrome browser. I did the same using postcss plugin but this gives same result. Looks like this has to do something with focus classes.

Actual Output I am getting:
[image: Chrome Browser Output]

The output I want:
[image: TailwindCSS Official Website Output]
Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Tailwind CSS</title>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
          <div class="md:col-span-1">
            <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
              <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Profile</h3>
              <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
                This information will be displayed publicly so be careful what you share.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
            <form action="#" method="POST">
              <div class="shadow sm:rounded-md sm:overflow-hidden">
                <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-6 sm:p-6">
                  <div class="col-span-3 sm:col-span-2">
                    <label for="company_website" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                      Website
                    </label>
                    <div class="mt-1 flex rounded-md shadow-sm">
                      <span class="inline-flex items-center px-3 rounded-l-md border border-r-0 border-gray-300 bg-gray-50 text-gray-500 text-sm">
                        http://
                      </span>
                      <input type="text" name="company_website" id="company_website" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 flex-1 block w-full rounded-none rounded-r-md sm:text-sm border-gray-300" placeholder="www.example.com">
                    </div>
                  </div>
      
                  <div>
                    <label for="about" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                      About
                    </label>
                    <div class="mt-1">
                      <textarea id="about" name="about" rows="3" class="shadow-sm focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 mt-1 block w-full sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md" placeholder="you@example.com"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <p class="mt-2 text-sm text-gray-500">
                      Brief description for your profile. URLs are hyperlinked.
                    </p>
                  </div>
      
                  <div>
                    <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                      Photo
                    </label>
                    <div class="mt-1 flex items-center">
                      <span class="inline-block h-12 w-12 rounded-full overflow-hidden bg-gray-100">
                        <svg class="h-full w-full text-gray-300" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                          <path d="M24 20.993V24H0v-2.996A14.977 14.977 0 0112.004 15c4.904 0 9.26 2.354 11.996 5.993zM16.002 8.999a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z" />
                        </svg>
                      </span>
                      <button type="button" class="ml-5 bg-white py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm text-sm leading-4 font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                        Change
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
      
                  <div>
                    <label class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                      Cover photo
                    </label>
                    <div class="mt-1 flex justify-center px-6 pt-5 pb-6 border-2 border-gray-300 border-dashed rounded-md">
                      <div class="space-y-1 text-center">
                        <svg class="mx-auto h-12 w-12 text-gray-400" stroke="currentColor" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 48 48" aria-hidden="true">
                          <path d="M28 8H12a4 4 0 00-4 4v20m32-12v8m0 0v8a4 4 0 01-4 4H12a4 4 0 01-4-4v-4m32-4l-3.172-3.172a4 4 0 00-5.656 0L28 28M8 32l9.172-9.172a4 4 0 015.656 0L28 28m0 0l4 4m4-24h8m-4-4v8m-12 4h.02" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
                        </svg>
                        <div class="flex text-sm text-gray-600">
                          <label for="file-upload" class="relative cursor-pointer bg-white rounded-md font-medium text-indigo-600 hover:text-indigo-500 focus-within:outline-none focus-within:ring-2 focus-within:ring-offset-2 focus-within:ring-indigo-500">
                            <span>Upload a file</span>
                            <input id="file-upload" name="file-upload" type="file" class="sr-only">
                          </label>
                          <p class="pl-1">or drag and drop</p>
                        </div>
                        <p class="text-xs text-gray-500">
                          PNG, JPG, GIF up to 10MB
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                  <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                    Save
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="hidden sm:block" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="py-5">
          <div class="border-t border-gray-200"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
        <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
          <div class="md:col-span-1">
            <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
              <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Personal Information</h3>
              <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
                Use a permanent address where you can receive mail.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
            <form action="#" method="POST">
              <div class="shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
                <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white sm:p-6">
                  <div class="grid grid-cols-6 gap-6">
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                      <label for="first_name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">First name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" autocomplete="given-name" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
      
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                      <label for="last_name" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Last name</label>
                      <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" autocomplete="family-name" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
      
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-4">
                      <label for="email_address" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Email address</label>
                      <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address" autocomplete="email" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
      
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3">
                      <label for="country" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Country / Region</label>
                      <select id="country" name="country" autocomplete="country" class="mt-1 block w-full py-2 px-3 border border-gray-300 bg-white rounded-md shadow-sm focus:outline-none focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 sm:text-sm">
                        <option>United States</option>
                        <option>Canada</option>
                        <option>Mexico</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
      
                    <div class="col-span-6">
                      <label for="street_address" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">Street address</label>
                      <input type="text" name="street_address" id="street_address" autocomplete="street-address" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
      
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-6 lg:col-span-2">
                      <label for="city" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">City</label>
                      <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
      
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3 lg:col-span-2">
                      <label for="state" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">State / Province</label>
                      <input type="text" name="state" id="state" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
      
                    <div class="col-span-6 sm:col-span-3 lg:col-span-2">
                      <label for="postal_code" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">ZIP / Postal</label>
                      <input type="text" name="postal_code" id="postal_code" autocomplete="postal-code" class="mt-1 focus:ring-indigo-500 focus:border-indigo-500 block w-full shadow-sm sm:text-sm border-gray-300 rounded-md">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                  <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                    Save
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="hidden sm:block" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="py-5">
          <div class="border-t border-gray-200"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="mt-10 sm:mt-0">
        <div class="md:grid md:grid-cols-3 md:gap-6">
          <div class="md:col-span-1">
            <div class="px-4 sm:px-0">
              <h3 class="text-lg font-medium leading-6 text-gray-900">Notifications</h3>
              <p class="mt-1 text-sm text-gray-600">
                Decide which communications you'd like to receive and how.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mt-5 md:mt-0 md:col-span-2">
            <form action="#" method="POST">
              <div class="shadow overflow-hidden sm:rounded-md">
                <div class="px-4 py-5 bg-white space-y-6 sm:p-6">
                  <fieldset>
                    <legend class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">By Email</legend>
                    <div class="mt-4 space-y-4">
                      <div class="flex items-start">
                        <div class="flex items-center h-5">
                          <input id="comments" name="comments" type="checkbox" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
                          <label for="comments" class="font-medium text-gray-700">Comments</label>
                          <p class="text-gray-500">Get notified when someones posts a comment on a posting.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="flex items-start">
                        <div class="flex items-center h-5">
                          <input id="candidates" name="candidates" type="checkbox" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
                          <label for="candidates" class="font-medium text-gray-700">Candidates</label>
                          <p class="text-gray-500">Get notified when a candidate applies for a job.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="flex items-start">
                        <div class="flex items-center h-5">
                          <input id="offers" name="offers" type="checkbox" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300 rounded">
                        </div>
                        <div class="ml-3 text-sm">
                          <label for="offers" class="font-medium text-gray-700">Offers</label>
                          <p class="text-gray-500">Get notified when a candidate accepts or rejects an offer.</p>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                  <fieldset>
                    <div>
                      <legend class="text-base font-medium text-gray-900">Push Notifications</legend>
                      <p class="text-sm text-gray-500">These are delivered via SMS to your mobile phone.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mt-4 space-y-4">
                      <div class="flex items-center">
                        <input id="push_everything" name="push_notifications" type="radio" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300">
                        <label for="push_everything" class="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                          Everything
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="flex items-center">
                        <input id="push_email" name="push_notifications" type="radio" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300">
                        <label for="push_email" class="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                          Same as email
                        </label>
                      </div>
                      <div class="flex items-center">
                        <input id="push_nothing" name="push_notifications" type="radio" class="focus:ring-indigo-500 h-4 w-4 text-indigo-600 border-gray-300">
                        <label for="push_nothing" class="ml-3 block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700">
                          No push notifications
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="px-4 py-3 bg-gray-50 text-right sm:px-6">
                  <button type="submit" class="inline-flex justify-center py-2 px-4 border border-transparent shadow-sm text-sm font-medium rounded-md text-white bg-indigo-600 hover:bg-indigo-700 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                    Save
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Tailwind UI Documentation](https://tailwindui.com/documentation#getting-set-up):

> All of the examples in Tailwind UI rely on the default Tailwind CSS v2.0 configuration, but some rely on additional first-party plugins like `@tailwindcss/forms`, `@tailwindcss/typography`, and `@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio`.

In particular, I believe you need to install [@tailwindcss/forms](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-forms) and add it to `tailwind.config.js` in order to get your desired styling. Simply including the Tailwind CSS file via a CDN won't include all the styles you need for forms.